# Firebase reads increasing even without a read call

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I developed a flutter app that takes some data as an input and uploads that to firebase but when I see the billing section (on Firebase console) after uploading some data I can only see reads are increasing abnormally while I haven't performed any read operation. Reads are increasing not by a factor of 1 but with a factor of 5, any help will be appreciated.

following is the code for my CRUD:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class CrudMethods {
  void printing() {
    print("hii");
  }

  bool isLoggedIn() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() == null)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }

  Future<void> addData(val) async {
    print("hiii");
    Firestore.instance.collection("User").add(val).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

I call addData() with a map as an input when i want to input data.

Comment: Most likely it is because of the fact that you have the Firebase console open.

Comment: My writes are also not increasing that much only reads are increasing I probably have pressed the submit button which triggers add data about 20 times. But its showing only about 6 writes.

Comment: @AlexMamo tnx I observed it and you are right.